# How to calculate ratio of two binomial coefficient

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I'm working through the book Probability and Statistics by DeGroot, 3rd edition.

In section 1.8 #2 It asks which of the following is larger: $\binom{93}{30}$ or $\binom{93}{31}$

In the solutions manual it says:

The ratio of $\binom{93}{30}$ to $\binom{93}{31}$ is 31/63 < 1 so $\binom{93}{31}$ is larger.

The ratio part makes sense, but I don't get how they got the values 31 and 63.

$\binom{93}{30}$ $\ne$ 31 nor is $\binom{93}{31}$ $\ne$ 63.

I read the chapter and went back and forth looking for where they might have explained this, but couldn't find it. Can someone tell me how they got those values?

Comment: Take a good look at [Pascal's triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal's_triangle), and notice that $\displaystyle{n\choose k}$ is strictly increasing for $0\le k\le\bigg\lfloor\dfrac n2\bigg\rfloor,$ and strictly decreasing for $\bigg\lceil\dfrac n2\bigg\rceil\le k\le n.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use the formula 
$${n \choose p} = \frac{n!}{p!(n-p)!}$$

Here, you will have
$$\frac{{93 \choose 30}}{{93\choose 31}} = \frac{93!}{30!63!} \times \frac{31!62!}{93!} = \frac{31}{63}$$

Answer (score 2):

Start with the formula for binomial coefficients:

$${a\choose b} = \frac{a!}{b!(a-b)!}$$

and notice much cancellation when you take the ratio of both the given coefficients.

Answer (score 1):

The ratio of numbers is:

```
fact(93) / (fact(30) * fact(63)) : fact(93) / (fact(31) * fact(62))

fact(31) * fact(62) / fact(30) * fact(63)

31 / 63
```